# An alternative for "ignorance"

Tags: word-request, synonyms

Can you help me make this sentence more clear? Especially the part about users' compliance.

> Two issues of the computer system are lack of customization and ignorance of users’ compliance.

I want to say that the design of the computer system does not take into account the way that users respond to the system. But I just want to say it in one word: ignorance, negligence,...
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Something similar to [**ergonomic**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ergonomic)? Can we say "the computer system is not ergonomic"?

Comment: "Ignorance" is okay, but "users' compliance" doesn't make much sense. Users don't "comply" with computer systems. It's hard for me to suggest an alternative without knowing what the users are having trouble with. (Do they find it hard to use? Does it lead them to make errors? Are they tasks they want to do that are not supported?)

Comment: It is an alert system which gives warning about a possible malfunction. When users receive an alert, they need to assess the situation and perform some preventive/corrective actions as needed. So compliance essentially here refers to whether users "listen" to the system.

Comment: "ignorance" seems a perfectly good word. You could equally use "unawareness".  However, if it is clarity you want, why not just say "lack of knowledge".